# Android - Duplicate avoidance without Object instanciation

Tags: java, android, duplicates

What is the best way to check if an amount of Strings are duplicates inside a rendering-function - this means i do not want any Object instanciation here?

Background:
I am drawing Strings inside to a canvas like:

```
public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    while(stringSource.hasMoreStringsAvailable()) {
        String st = stringSource.getNextString();
        //Check String and draw only if it has not been drawn already.

    }
```

The usage of a HashSet would occur the creation of a Map.Element - instance for each object. Android's Sparse-Array class looks good but only accepty int-keys. So both of them are not applicable here.

Information: 
The source can deliver any String at any time. 
The maximum amount of possible Strings is available.

What is a good way herefore? Is there a better (and especially more easy) solution than creating an own HashMap based on a String[]?

Comment: Do you need to check at render time? Why not check if a String is a duplicate before adding it to your set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android already has `Set` and `Map` implementations backed by arrays, called `ArraySet` and `ArrayMap`.

These implementations use a lot less memory than `HashSet` and `HashMap`.